# Setting up jest mocks - one way works the other doesn't

Tags: jestjs

When setting up jest mocks for a class what does not work for me with an error of "_TextObj.TextObj is not a constructor" is

```
import { TextObj, } from "@entities/TextObj";
jest.mock('@entities/TextObj', () => {
   return jest.fn().mockImplementation((config: TextObjConfig) => {
      return { ...

      }
   });
});
```

According to https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter I had expected the first version to work too - or not?

however what works is

```
import { TextObj, } from "@entities/TextObj";
jest.mock('@entities/TextObj');
 ...
beforeAll(() => {
      TextObj.mockImplementation((config: TextObjConfig) => {
         return {
..
         }
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextObj` is a named export and you're trying to mock default export which is why it is throwing the error `_TextObj.TextObj is not a constructor`.

For mocking named export, you need to do following the changes i.e return an object that contains `TestObj` property:

```
import { TextObj, } from "@entities/TextObj";
jest.mock('@entities/TextObj', () => {
   TestObj: jest.fn().mockImplementation((config: TextObjConfig) => {
      return { ...

      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Subrato. Based on your info I found that with
jest.mock('@frontend/entities/TextObj', () => {
   return {
      TextObj: jest.fn().mockImplementation((config: TextObjConfig) => {
         return {...       }
      })
   }
}); it works. I.e. needed one more return before TextObj: